# Text field that expands horizontally to fit the text contents

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a text field that expands horizontally to fit the text contents, bounded with a maxWidth and minWidth in pixels.

`TextEditingController()` does not appear to expose the width of the text, and it seems to always expand to maximum available width, even if wrapped with `Flexible()`